# Knockout firing click binding on applyBindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Recently I've separated out ViewModel to a separate JavaScript file.

```
var Report = (function($) {
    var initialData = [];
    var viewModel = {
        reports: ko.observableArray(initialData),
        preview: function(path) {
            // preview report
        },
        otherFunctions: function() {}
    };
    return viewModel;
})(jQuery);​
```

Here is the HTML and Knockout related code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/report/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(Report, document.body);
    });
</script>
```

HTML user interface has a button on which click is data bind to preview function in the view model

```
<input type="button" name="Preview" id="Preview" class="btnPreview" 
    data-bind="click: Report.preview('url/to/report')" />
```

**Problem** preview method is called when the following line execute in $(document).ready() function

```
ko.applyBindings(Report, document.body);
```

That is without user clicking on the Preview button preview function is fired. What could be the reason for this behavior? The whole stuff was working fine when I'd view model JavaScript in the HTML page itself.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The reason is, that you're indeed invoking the preview function (because writing `functionName` means referring to the function, writing `functionName()` means calling it).

So `data-bind="click: Report.preview"` would be working as expected, but without handing over the parameter.

As [the manual](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) states (on a different topic, but this still applies):

> If you need to pass more parameters, one way to do it is by wrapping your handler in a function literal that takes in a parameter, as in this example:

```
<button data-bind="click: function(data, event) { myFunction(data, event, 'param1', 'param2') }">
    Click me
</button>
```

or in your case:

```
data-bind="click: function() { Report.preview('url/to/report') }"
```

Another solution would be to make preview() return a function (pretty much the same thing actually):

```
preview: function(path) {
    return function() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Took me a minute to get this answer. The clarification I needed: it's because you're calling `Report.preview` with `()` that it executes the call instead of returning the function pointer. Without brackets it would work as expected.

Answer (score 24):

Another solution is to use 'bind' construct:

```
data-bind="click: Report.preview.bind($data, 'url/to/report')"
```

where the first parameter to bind() will become the 'this' in the called function.