# Knockout - Event seems to fire on page load?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a ViewModel which has a dropdown like so:

```
<select data-bind="options: orderDropdown,
    value: selectedOrder, 
    optionsCaption: '---',
    event: { change: loadOrderDetails }">
</select>
```

Then the `loadOrderDetails` is set like this:

```
// loads details of selected order
self.loadOrderDetails = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/OrderDetails",
        data: { id: self.selectedOrder() },
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            self.orderDetails(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, this event seems to fire when the page loads as when I look in the console I see this:

`GET http://localhost:52559/api/OrderDetails 400 (Bad Request)`

Any idea how I can prevent this from firing on page load?

Comment: It's quite possible that the event will fire when you either set the value of orderDropdown or the value of selectedOrder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience with the knockout options binding has been that it will trigger an update when loaded if it doesn't have a value defined.

So, if "selectedOrder" is just a ko.observable() with no value then it will set its value as the first item in the "orderDropdown" array.  That will cause your change event to fire.

Comment: Yeah, I've added a check to see if my `selectedOrder` property is undefined or not..

Comment: One additional caveat -- if you are toggling the visibility on your control, knockout binds the select first, then hides it. If you have a hidden select with no value defined, the update event may fire anyway.

Comment: I checked putting a default value `ko.observable('somevalueExistingInList')` and still , the change event is being fired on page load. :/

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
<select data-bind="options: orderDropdown,
    value: selectedOrder, 
    optionsCaption: '---',
    event: { change: function() { loadOrderDetails() } }">
</select>
```

I got solution from this particular answer on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10119888/1301774