# Knockout Removing a Clicked Row

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a jQuery UI popup that has an embedded table. The user can click a "+" sign at the bottom of the popup to add a row to the table. Each row contains 4 elements (3 text inputs & 1 "remove row" button). Adding rows is easy but I'm having trouble identifying the remove button's row index when passing it to my "removeRow(index)" function.

This is the HTML

```
    <table id="item-config-table" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>                    
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Description</th>                    
                <th>Part #</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="item-config-body">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text">
                </td>
                <td>
                    //This line is the delete button
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-minus" style="vertical-align:middle;padding:4px;" data-bind="click: function(data, event) {$root.RemoveConfigRow(data,event,$(this))}"><span style="font-family:'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; vertical-align:central;color:#1F497D;"></span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is my function

```
 RemoveConfigRow = function (data, event, object) {
            var index = object.parent().parent().index();
            var count = $('#item-config-body tr').length;
            if (count > 1)
                document.getElementById('item-config-body').deleteRow(index);
        };
```

What I'm trying to do is pass the reference to the current element **a** and then have the function to back up two levels to the **tr**. From there I want to find it's index in the body to remove it.

When the function is called an object is passed, but the data within doesn't seem to have any ties to the link element that was clicked. Subsequently calling **.parent().parent().index()** on **object** returns **-1**. My guess is the "this" binding is bound to something else when passed to the function.

This post got me really close, but he's passing hard coded parameters and not using the keyword 'this'
[Knockout firing click binding on applyBindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119767/knockout-firing-click-binding-on-applybindings)

Comment: You are not using knockout.js. Are you ?

Comment: I am. The stuff in the <a> with the data-bind is all run through knockout js

Comment: @Rafiki, if you set the background to pink on `object.parent()` what turns pink, the cell or the row?

Comment: @Charles The object.parent() object is undefined so it wasn't changing anything. If I inspect "object" it shows me a list of all my observables and functions.

Comment: You're mixing jQuery and knockout for DOM manipulation which is bad practice.  What is the context of the binding in the click event? I.e. there should be either applyBinding(vm) or data-bind: with|foreach that indicates  the context. This would be 'data'. I think variable 'this' would be the same

Comment: well, that explains why `object.parent().parent() === -1` I guess. Does event have parentElement on it? If so, you could go with `var elem = event.parentElement.parentElement; elem.remove()` if you really wanted to.

Comment: @Jonathan The applyBinding is done on document.Ready and then the "insertRow" button (not pictured above) calls applyBinding(vm, newRow) to apply the bindings to new rows as they're added. But if the answer is to not use jQuery coupled with Knockout, I can role with that. I just don't understand the behind the scenes enough to know why they can't work together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not do this:

```
document.getElementById('item-config-body').deleteRow(index);
```

If you want to do DOM manipulation, don't use Knockout. Your contract with Knockout is that you will control the ViewModel and Knockout will control the DOM.

In Knockout, your problem reduces to adding and removing elements of an ObservableArray.

```js
uid=1;

vm = {
  arr: ko.observableArray(),
  remove: function(data) {
    vm.arr.remove(data);
  },
  add: function() {
    vm.arr.push(uid++);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: arr">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text:$data"></td>
      <td>
        <button data-bind="click:$parent.remove">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: add">Add</button>
```

Comment: @Rafiki This is what I'm alluding to in my previous comment. You haven't posted your full viewmodel to get a rewrite here, but I suggest implementing what Roy has into your view model and letting us know troubles that arise and/or updating your question with revised code.

Comment: Thanks guys for all of your help. I really didn't want to spend this much time on the front end, but I'll take that to DevRant. @Jonathan I appreciate your help as well.